# xor operation in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Is there an xor operation in alloy, if not, how can I define it:

I would like to have a predicate named xor that gets two predicates as argument and it holds true when their xor hold true.

more elaborately, if I have P1 and P2, I know that I can have P3 defined as bellow:

```
pred P3(){
   (P1 and (not P2)) or ((not P1) and P2)
}
```

to be an xor of P1 and P2, but I want to define xor (or any other formula connectives), put it in a library and use them later. so I would like my P3 get predicates as the argument. Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alloy has unfortunately no Boolean type. Without a proper type, you can't declare arguments for your predicate. Your approach seems thus a lost cause.

I can think of two ugly tricks both involving the use of util/boolean or your own Boolean definition to make things work.

In both tricks your XOR predicate shall take two Bool arguments.

```
pred xor[ x,y:Bool){
   x != y
}
```

**In the first trick**, represent all your propositions as singleton signatures(e.g. P1 and P2) rather than predicates. Have those signatures declare a Bool typed field (e.g. bool) and set this field in a signature fact using the formula you would put in your predicate P1 and P2.

call then your predicate xor as follows :

```
xor[P1.bool ,P2.bool]
```

**In the second trick**
you keep your propositions represented as predicates (P1 and P2), but when calling xor, you'll need to "cast" the truth value of those predicates to Bool.

```
xor[(P1 implies True else False ),(P2 implies True else False )]
```

Again in my opinion both solutions are ugly. It would be nice to have a broader view of what you would like to achieve in order to come with a better solution.

Answer (score 7):

The `xor` operation can just be written as `iff not`.